# How to convert unstructured data to structured data?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I'm trying to write a javaScript program that would convert unstructured data to structured data.
The problem looks something like this.
[image: The contexts are chosen by me and the aim of the program is to find the data that are related to the context]

The contexts are chosen by me and the aim of the program is to find the data that are related to the context. Currently I have been using regex to extract relevant information like RAM, ppi etc. but it does not work most of the time. Is there any anything else that can help me solve this problem?
Here's something that i have written:

```
//modules
const fs = require('fs');

//main code section
function extractInfo(sentence,context)
{
    var regex= / /gm;
    if(context==='processor')
        regex =/\w{1,}.\w{1,}.\d{1,}/gm;
    else if(context==='RAM')
        regex= /\d{1,}GB/gm;
    else if(context==='price')
        regex= /Rs. \d{1,}.\d{1,}/gm;
    else if(context==='camera')
        regex = /\d{1,}.megapixel/gm;
    else if(context==='storage')
        regex = /\d{1,}GB/gm;


    let match = regex.exec(sentence);
    if(match)
    {
        return(match[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        return('null');
    }
}
 const context = ['price','screen size','pixel density','processor','GPU','camera','battery capacity','RAM','storage'];
 var paragraph = fs.readFileSync("./text.txt").toString('utf-8').replace(/\n/g, '');
// //paragraph = paragraph.toLowerCase();
var sentences = paragraph.replace(/([.?!])\s*(?=[A-Z])/g, "$1|").split("|");
sentences.forEach(item=>{
 for(var i=0;i<context.length;i++)
    {
        if(item.includes(context[i]))
            {
                console.log(context[i]+" : "+ extractInfo(item,context[i]));
             }
        }
     });
```

And using this I'm able to get an output like this which I would put later in a json document (Currently I'm just focusing on the algorithm):

```
$ node app.js 
processor : Qualcomm Snapdragon 865
RAM : 12GB
camera : 108-megapixel
camera : null
camera : 25-megapixel
storage : 256GB
price : Rs. 64,299
```

Comment: NLP is a big challenge of this century, and you probably don't want to solve it yourself

Comment: I would probably suggest to find some sources with some kind of structured data, like a website, and scrape information from there, which might be simple than totally unstructured data